# Show meta box only for default page template

Tags: php, functions, metabox, page-template

I'm having an issue with one of my meta box. I want the meta box displayed only on the default page template editing `page.php`.

The meta box doesn't show up on the editing page.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'page_add_meta_boxes', 1);
function page_add_meta_boxes() {
  global $post;
  if(!empty($post)) {
    $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
    if($pageTemplate == 'page.php') {
      add_meta_box( 'page-repeatable-fields', 'Index', 'page_repeatable_meta_box_display', 'page', 'normal', 'low');
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Code updated following the comments of @SallyCJ

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'page_add_meta_boxes', 10, 2);
function page_add_meta_boxes($post_type, $post) {
  if(!empty($post)) {
   $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
   if(in_array( $pageTemplate, array( 'default', 'page.php' ) ) ) {
     add_meta_box( 'page-repeatable-fields', 'Index', 'page_repeatable_meta_box_display', 'page', 'normal', 'low');
   }
 }
}
```

After checking with `var_dump( $pageTemplate );` the result is:

```
"String(0) "" "
```

Note: If use a custom template page to display the metabox, it works.

Comment: PS: I hope my answer helps, and if you haven't, you should check the tutorial on creating *meta **block*** - see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/metabox/ - and consider creating meta block instead. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "*Default Template*" option is selected from the Template dropdown, then WordPress will set the value of the `_wp_page_template` meta to `default` and not `page.php`, so that's most likely the reason why your meta box is not showing/added.

So I would use `if ( in_array( $pageTemplate, array( 'default', 'page.php' ) ) )` instead of `if ( $pageTemplate == 'page.php' )`.

Additionally, I would also use the `$post` variable that's available as the [second parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes/#parameters) for the meta box function:

```php
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'page_add_meta_boxes', 10, 2); // require the 2nd parameter
function page_add_meta_boxes($post_type, $post) { // and define it in the function head
    //global $post; // <- no need to do this

    // your code
}
```

## Update

If the meta value is empty (`''`), then the template will be the default, e.g. `page.php` for the `page` post type.

So you could use `if ( ! $pageTemplate || in_array( $pageTemplate, array( 'default', 'page.php' ) ) )` instead of the one I suggested above.

Or actually, you could use [`get_page_template_slug()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template_slug/) which is much easier. :) Example based on your updated code:

```php
function page_add_meta_boxes($post_type, $post) {
  $pageTemplate = get_page_template_slug( $post );
  if(! $pageTemplate || 'page.php' === $pageTemplate) {
   add_meta_box( 'page-repeatable-fields', 'Index', 'page_repeatable_meta_box_display', 'page', 'normal', 'low');
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the meta box still doesn't show up in the editor.

Comment: In that case, then do a `error_log( $pageTemplate );` (or just as a quick debugging, try `var_dump( $pageTemplate );`) before your conditional, and see what the meta value is. Also, it might be better if you edit your question and include your updated code?

Comment: And if the block editor is enabled, you may also need to set [`__block_editor_compatible_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/backward-compatibility/meta-box/) to `true`, although it actually defaults to `true`.

Comment: I updated the question with your code.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I forgot that the meta value could be empty. So try the code in the "Update" part?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Just tried the code in the update and It works like a charm, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code i guess it should work correctly

```php
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'page_add_meta_boxes');
function page_add_meta_boxes(){
    global $post;
    if(!empty($post)):
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
        $pageTemplate = ($pageTemplate == "page.php" || empty($pageTemplate) || $pageTemplate == " " || $pageTemplate == "default" )?true:false;
        if($pageTemplate):
            add_meta_box(
                    'page-repeatable-fields',
                    'Index',
                    'page_repeatable_meta_box_display',
                    'page',
                    'normal',
                    'low'
                )
        endif;
    endif;
}
```